# Using dplyr to render list from value in dataframe (r)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe and am trying to get a specfic output from it (see below).

```
   issueShort  IssueDescription   source   searchWords  defineLib1   defineLib2  defineNeutral defineCon2  defineCon1 
      <chr>       <chr>              <chr>    <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       <chr>         <chr>       <chr>      
    1 ConeyBarret Confirmation of A~ NA       Coney, Barr~ Strong, una~ Text sugge~ Takes no pos~ Text sugge~ Strong, un~
    2 Roe         Roe v Wade decisi~ NA       Roe, Wade, ~ NA           NA          NA            NA          NA         
    3 TaxCut2017  Supports 2017 GOP~ https:/~ tax cut, tr~ NA           NA          NA            NA          NA         
    4 ObamaCare   Supports Affordab~ https:/~ ObamaCare, ~ NA           NA          NA            NA          NA
```

Here is what I am currently doing.

```
searchWords = codebook %>%
      filter(issueShort == 'ConeyBarret') %>%
      select(searchWords) %>%
      unlist( use.names=FALSE)
```

I want searchwords to be in the format of h. What is the best way to do this?

```
h <-c("coney", "barret")


    > searchWords
    [1] "Coney, Barret"
    > h
    [1] "coney"  "barret"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem right now is that your `searchWords` column is a character vector.  It sounds like you actually want that column to be a list column containing different length character vectors.  You could try this:

```
searchWords <- codebook %>%
      dplyr::filter(issueShort == 'ConeyBarret') %>%
      dplyr::mutate(searchWords = list(strsplit(searchWords, split = ", "))) %>%
      dplyr::select(searchWords)
```